# Could not start ElasticSearch in Azure WebApp

Tags: java, azure, elasticsearch, azure-web-app-service

I downloaded [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch), ran `bin/elasticsearch.bat` and it worked on my local machine. Then I added the elasticsearch folder to my repository and updated the deploymentscript (deploy.cmd), adding these lines:

```
echo starting ElasticSearch...
elasticsearch-1.7.2\bin\elasticsearch.bat
echo ElasticSearch started!
```

After pushing my repository to my Azure Website, this error occurs in the log:

```
starting ElasticSearch...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Java is turned on in the configuration of my WebApp. So what's the problem? Why couldn't the Java VM be created?

Edit: `Could not reserve enough space for object heap` looks like I have less RAM, but I already tried it out with 3.5GB RAM and the error also occurs - ElasticSearch only uses 155 MB RAM on my local machine)

Edit2:
After some tries I get a new error log:

```
starting ElasticSearch...
[2015-10-15 12:59:18,879][INFO ][node                     ] [Marsha Rosenberg] version[1.7.2], pid[3728], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
[2015-10-15 12:59:18,879][INFO ][node                     ] [Marsha Rosenberg] initializing ...
[2015-10-15 12:59:19,273][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Marsha Rosenberg] loaded [], sites []
[2015-10-15 12:59:20,692][INFO ][env                      ] [Marsha Rosenberg] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Windows (D:)]], net usable_space [13.5gb], net total_space [32gb], types [NTFS]
[2015-10-15 12:59:28,869][INFO ][node                     ] [Marsha Rosenberg] initialized
[2015-10-15 12:59:28,869][INFO ][node                     ] [Marsha Rosenberg] starting ...
{1.7.2}: Startup Failed ...
- ChannelException[Failed to create a selector.]
    IOException[Unable to establish loopback connection]
        SocketException[Address family not supported by protocol family: bind]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, Using the deployment script to start up ElasticSearch on Azure WebApp is not a correct way.

In the doc https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox,  the section "Network endpoint listening" says "The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports; applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from the internet."  So I think that  your issue "JavaVM could not be created" was caused by ElasticSearch cannot bind the port 9200 as HTTP listener.

If you want to use ElasticSearch, you should use Azure VM or setup Facetflow ElasticSearch from Azure Marketplace.  Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/elasticsearch/ for Elastic on Azure VM, and refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/facetflow/facetflow/ to know Facetflow ElasticSearch on Azure.

Even you just want to add the search function into your webapp, the Azure Search may be a good choice. About Azure Search, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/search/.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the elasticsearch config file so that it now listens to port 80 (works on my local machine) but I get the same error in my WebApp deployment. I already used a VM for ES, but I want to move to WebApp because I don't want to have the high maintenance as I have with a VM. I will take a look into Azure Search, but I would prefer the ES in a WebApp.

Comment: @Munchkin Azure WebApp contains IIS proxy, Tomcat or Jetty Servlet Container for Java, and WebJob as backend task without http(s) listener. It's not suitable for a standalone service process. And the deployment script is only for deploying web project into Azure, not for startup a service. So I recommend you to use Facetflow ES with free pricing in the Marketplace of Azure Preview Portal if you don't want to use a VM for ES. Thanks for your feedback. Any concern about ES on Azure, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is failing due to its attempt to make local requests. Please see [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#local-address-requests) for more information on the restrictions on the Azure Web App sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` argument to `elasticsearch.bat`.

Also make sure that `JAVA_HOME` is set to Java 8 and not Java 7. The path on Azure Web Apps is `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`

Also keep in mind that if you run multiple elasticsearch servers on the same VM (in the same App Service Plan) they won't all listen on `9200`. By default I think elasticsearch tries ports from `9200 - 9300`, so take a look at the stdout.

You may wanna disable clustering and auto-discovery in your `elasticsearch.yml` since you can't form a cluster anyway by setting

```
node.local: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast: false
index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0
```

This is probably fine for testing/dev scenario, but for production you really should consider running elasticsearch on it's own VM, or cluster of VMs, that are running in their own VNET and join the site to the VNET through VPN. Then you'll have a full elasticsearch cluster that's protected behind a VPN and the web app will talk to it over it's private IP.

**Finally**, keep in mind that `elasticsearch.bat` is blocking. If you do that in your deploy.cmd, it'll block your deployment forever. (well not really forever, there is a timeout and it'll kill elasticsearch at the end). You wanna try to run it from [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console). basically go to `https://<yourSitenName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and you'll have a `cmd` window to run stuff from. You can click on the `Use old console`. The difference between the old and new, is that the new console is interactive (you'll see stdout as it happens on the server) but has timeout of 30 minutes, while the old one isn't interactive (the output will only be displayed once the command finish running), but doesn't have a timeout.

While the elasticsearch server is running, open another instance of the Kudu Console and run `curl localhost:9200` to verify that it's running.